# Returning distinct values from SQL with BLOB columns and Inner Joins

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, distinct

I need to return distinct records from 2 tables. The problem is one of the columns is a blob and I also need it for reconstructing the file.
I saw some solutions but in none of them the original query(without the distinct) included a inner join.
Here's my query

```
SELECT dop.DSC_DOCUMENTO, adp.NOM_ARQUIVO_ANEXO,adp.CON_ARQUIVO_ANEXO
  FROM documento_os_pe dop
  JOIN anexo_documento_pe adp 
    ON dop.NUM_SEQUENCIAL_DOCUMENTO = adp.NUM_SEQUENCIAL_DOCUMENTO
  WHERE dop.ind_anexo = 'Y' AND DOP.NUM_PE = 54 
  ORDER BY dop.NUM_OS DESC;
```

Comment: What solutions have you tried and what was wrong with them?

Comment: This suggests your solution may be a to_char(blob), but only if the blob is small enough to fit in a varchar.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678881/how-to-use-group-by-on-a-clob-column-with-oracle

Comment: Some attitonal input here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.oracle.misc/wy4OorjaPQc

Comment: Alex Poole, I've tried to use a subquery using distinct in the same tables. didn't worked. I've tried to validate in  C#  with the response but I wanted something in the sql

Comment: If the `BLOB` is big, I would suggest adding an extra column to store its SHA-2 value, and compare this one instead.

Comment: what columns do you want to participate in distinct? Is the blob contents included too? It means do you want to compare blob contents to make result district?

Comment: I just need to compare the first two columns of my selected (dop.DSC_DOCUMENTO, adp.NOM_ARQUIVO_ANEXO) but I need to return the equivalent blob for using after....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved by validating the response on c#.
Before generating the file to show to the user I've constructed an dictionary without the duplicating files. I've used `OrderBy Desc` to return the latest files.