# How to update sql records by comparing duplicate strings?

Tags: sql

I have a table below:

```
id   |  echantillon_dta  |   Est_en_double 
1    |   Bonjour         |      null
2    |   Bonjour         |      null
3    |   Bonjour         |      null
4    |   Joke            |      null
5    |   Joke            |      null
6    |                   |      null
```

And after process query will show below:

```
id   |   echantillon_dta        |   Est_en_double 
1    |   Bonjour         |      1
2    |   Bonjour         |      1 
3    |   Bonjour         |      1 
4    |   Joke            |      4
5    |   Joke            |      4
6    |                   |      null
```

How to compare string vesus string? And how to update column like so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please show us what you've tried ?

Comment: GROUP BY and ORDER BY works with strings just fine, not sure how you reached that conclusion. Finding duplicates is a very common problem with many different solutions. If you want to read up on it, check this blog by Chris Saxon: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use update by `min(id)` when Record_Details is same.

and there is a misdescription   :
`6    |   Nope            |      6 //No duplicates found, stay null`
id 6 is no duplicate but `isDuplicate column` value is 6,shouldn't it be `null`?
so i use `having count(1) > 1` to slove it.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>   ("id" int, "Record_Details" varchar2(11), "isDuplicate" varchar2(4))
> ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT ALL 
>   INTO Table1 ("id", "Record_Details", "isDuplicate")
>        VALUES (1, 'Hello World', NULL)
>   INTO Table1 ("id", "Record_Details", "isDuplicate")
>        VALUES (2, 'Hello World', NULL)
>   INTO Table1 ("id", "Record_Details", "isDuplicate")
>        VALUES (3, 'Hello World', NULL)
>   INTO Table1 ("id", "Record_Details", "isDuplicate")
>        VALUES (4, 'Joke', NULL)
>   INTO Table1 ("id", "Record_Details", "isDuplicate")
>        VALUES (5, 'Joke', NULL)
>   INTO Table1 ("id", "Record_Details", "isDuplicate")
>        VALUES (6, 'Nope', NULL)
> SELECT * FROM dual
> ;
> ```

> ```
> update (
>   select T.*
>      , (select min("id") 
>         from Table1 Tmp 
>         where Tmp."Record_Details" = T."Record_Details"
>         group by Tmp."Record_Details" having count(1) > 1 --No duplicates found, stay null
>
>      ) as "new_isDuplicate"
>   from Table1 T
> )
> set "isDuplicate" = "new_isDuplicate"
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | Record_Details | isDuplicate
> -: | :------------- | :----------
>  1 | Hello World    | 1          
>  2 | Hello World    | 1          
>  3 | Hello World    | 1          
>  4 | Joke           | 4          
>  5 | Joke           | 4          
>  6 | Nope           | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7d11fee2c6a7c2a95696d10031fa1e0e)*

Comment: The GROUP BY statement fails on Oracle DB, with a [42000][932] ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB error. Presumably because I cant GROUP BY string type records

Comment: @CuriosLoner follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678881/how-to-use-group-by-on-a-clob-column-with-oracle

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the minimum `id` with the same `record_details`.

This should work:

```
select t.*,
       min(id) over (partition by record_details) as isDuplicate
from t;
```

If you want this as an `update`, a correlated subquery is a simple approach:

```
update t
    set isduplicate = (select min(t2.id)
                       from t t2
                       where t2.record_details = t.record_details
                      );
```

Comment: @CuriosLoner . . . Nothing in your question mentions `CLOB`s.

Comment: @CuriosLoner . . . You should probably ask a *new* question.  This question has already been answered and changing the question will invalidate answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement and analytic function to find the duplicates:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table_name ( id, Record_Details, isDuplicate ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Hello World', CAST( NULL AS NUMBER ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Hello World', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Hello World', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Joke',        NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Joke',        NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Nope',        NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Merge**:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         MIN( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Record_details ) AS dupe_id
  FROM   table_name
) src
ON (
    dst.ROWID = src.RID
AND dst.id <> src.dupe_id -- remove this line if you want to update all rows
) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET isDuplicate = dupe_id;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | RECORD_DETAILS | ISDUPLICATE
> -: | :------------- | ----------:
>  1 | Hello World    |        null
>  2 | Hello World    |           1
>  3 | Hello World    |           1
>  4 | Joke           |        null
>  5 | Joke           |           4
>  6 | Nope           |        null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=103ae1432557fc055c51f95a1a93f4d7)*